# Filter array using the $in operator in the $project stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Right now, it's not possible to use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator in the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) array aggregation operator.

Let's say this is the document schema:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    users: [
        {
            _id: 'a',
            accounts: ['x', 'y', 'z']
        },
        {
            _id: 'b',
            accounts: ['j','k','l']
        }
    ]
}
```

I want, using `aggregate`, to get the documents with filtered array of `users` based on the contents of the `accounts` array.

**IF** the `$in` would work with the `$filter` operator, I would expect it to look like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            'filtered_users': {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$users',
                    as: 'user',
                    cond: {
                        $in: ['$$user.accounts', ['x']]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

and return in the `filtered_users` only the first user since **x** is **in** his account.

But, as I said, this doesn't work and I get the error:

> "invalid operator '$in'"

because it isn't supported in the `$filter` operator.

Now I know I can do it with `$unwind` and using regular `$match` operators, but then it will be much longer (and uglier) aggregation with the need of using `$group` to set the results back as an array - **I don't want this**

My question is, if there is some other way to manipulate the `$filter` operator to get my desired results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `$in` is not supported in aggregate operation for array, the alternative would be for you to use `$setIsSubset`. For more information on this you can refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) link. The aggregate query would now look like

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        'filtered_users': {
            $filter: {
                input: '$users',
                as: 'user',
                cond: {
                   $setIsSubset: [['x'], '$$user.accounts']           
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

This query will return only elements which have `[x]` as a subset of the array in `user.accounts`.

Answer (score 13):

Starting From MongoDB 3.4, you can use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation operator in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([     
    {         
        "$project": {             
            "filtered_users": {                 
                "$filter": {                     
                    "input": "$users",                     
                    "as": "user",                     
                    "cond": { "$in": [ "x", "$$user.accounts" ] }                     
                }  
            }         
        }     
    } 
])
```

Comment: The right format would be something like this:
"cond": { "$in": [ "$$user.accounts", ["x"] ] }

Comment: @Eric I don't think so. OP's query is wrong. What OPs wants is *return in the filtered_users only the first user since **x** is in his account*. You missed that part in the question.