# Use $in when filtering a projection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, projection

I have an array of ids the user is following, and i can project the element when i need to check if one user with the $eq operater.

The working script looks like this:

```
IsFollowing : {
  $filter : {
    input : '$Following',
    as : 'following',
    cond : { 
      $eq : ['$$following.UserId', ObjectId('[requested user id]')]
    }
  }
}
```

Now a have a bunch of user ids, where i only want the user ids from my list:

```
{
    Following: {
        $filter : {
            input : '$Following',
            as : 'following',
            cond : { 
                $in : ['$$following.UserId', [ObjectId('[requested user´id]')....]]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i get this mongo error:

> Command failed with error 15999: 'invalid operator '$in'' on server....

I have to limit the result gives, since some users have thousands of people they follow.

Is it possible in any way to only fetch out the elements in Following, that are in a limited array of Object Ids?

Comment: `$in` operator  is only allowed in `$match` stage. Its only allowed in `$project` stage starting Mongo 3.3.5 version. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6146. You can do similar operation using `$setisSubset` operator. Something like `cond :{ $setIsSubset: [ ['$$following.UserId'], [ObjectId('[requested user´id]')....] ] }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoDB aggregation - filter array using $in operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444888/mongodb-aggregation-filter-array-using-in-operator)