# How to use arrays as filters by querying subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure on my mongodb collection:

```
{
"_id" : "5Ci9sLeBu2iPbWtR5",
"productId" : "010101111",
"description" : "PRODUCT EXAMPLE REF 1001",
"prices" : [ 
    {
        "priceId" : 10,
        "description" : "Promotions",
        "price" : 97.99
    },
    {
        "priceId" : 15,
        "description" : "Retail list",
        "price" : 105.65
    },
    {
        "priceId" : 20,
        "description" : "Standard list",
        "price" : 109.10
    }
]}
```

What I want is query only specific array of priceIds, for example: [10,20], resulting:

```
{
"_id" : "5Ci9sLeBu2iPbWtR5",
"productId" : "010101111",
"description" : "PRODUCT EXAMPLE REF 1001",
"prices" : [ 
    {
        "priceId" : 10,
        "description" : "Promotions",
        "price" : 97.99
    },
    {
        "priceId" : 20,
        "description" : "Standard list",
        "price" : 109.10
    }
]}
```

Using **$in** operator with **$filter** like this (the perfect imaginary scenario):

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
{$match: { "productId":"010101111" }},
{$project: { 
    "prices": {
        $filter: {
            input: "$prices",
            as: "price",
            cond: { $in: ["$$price.priceId",[10, 20]] }
        }
    }
}}])
```

it doesn't work, because mongodb complains about $in operator ("invalid operator '$in'").

Of course, I can do that with **$unwind**, but I'll have a performance problem, because I need to group again after all.

The closest answers I've found for my question were these two:

1. [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)
2. [Filter array using the $in operator in the $project stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444888/filter-array-using-the-in-operator-in-the-project-stage)

but none of them were about searching with array filter in subdocuments.

Comment: What is your mongo server version ? $in is available in 3.4

Comment: v3.2.18. Yes, I realized I'll need 3.4 to apply that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$in` operator is only valid within the aggregation pipeline for MongoDB 3.4+. However, a workaround involves using the set operators. Use **[`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset)** as substitute which returns true if all elements of the first set appear in the second set, including when the first set equals the second set:

```
cond: { $setIsSubset: [["$$price.priceId"],[10, 20]] }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The workaround worked in my current version (3.2). I figured out that I need to upgrade to 3.4 indeed.