# How to construct a mongo query that aggregates on two fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**TL;DR; How do I query mongo in a way that aggregates a collection two different ways?**

I'm learning to query MongoDB.  Suppose that I have a collection that contains the results of users submitting a questionnaire and then reviewers signing off that they have reviewed it.

A record in my collection looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 0,
    Questions:
    [
        {
            label: "fname",
            response: "Sir"
        },  
        {
            label: "lname",
            response: "Robin"
        },
        {
            label: "What is your name?",
            response: "Sir Robin of Camelot"
        },
        {
            label: "What is your quest?",
            response: "To seek the holy grail"
        },
        {
            label: "What is the capital of Asyria?",
            response: "I don't know that."
        }
    ],
    Signatures:
    [
        "Lancelot",
        "Arthur"
    ]
}
```

I am creating a report that will display a summary of each record.
For each record, I need to display the following:

- The first name
- The last name
- The number of signatures.

I am able to write an aggregate query that gets the first and last name.
I am also able to write an aggregate query that gets the number of signatures.

However, I am stuck when I try to write an aggregate query that gets both.

```
// In order to query the first and last name, I use this query:
[
    { $unwind: "$Questions" },
    { $match: { "Questions.Label": { $in: ["fname", "lname"] } } },
    { $project: { "Questions": 1 } },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", Questions: { $push: "$Questions" } } }
]

// In order to query the number of signatures, I use this query:
[
    { $project: { "SignatureCount": { $size: "$Signatures" } } }
]
```

Everything works with these two queries, but I want to write a single query that returns the data all together.

So, for example, if the example record above were the only record in my collection, I would want the query to return this:

```
{
    _id: 0,
    Questions:
    [
        {
            label: "fname",
            response: "Sir"
        },  
        {
            label: "lname",
            response: "Robin"
        }
    ],
    SignatureCount: 2
}
```

Comment: Might require an edit: the input document uses `label` fields and the aggregation query uses `Label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the query to get both in single project stage in 3.4 version.

Use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter Questions.

```
 [
  {"$match":{"Questions.Label":{"$in":["fname", "lname"]}},
  {"$project":{
    "Questions":{
      "$filter":{
        "input":"$Questions",
        "as":"q",
        "cond":{"$in":["$$q.Label",["fname","lname"]]}
      }
    },
    "SignatureCount":{"$size":"$Signatures"}
  }}
]
```

Comment: I'm seeing an error that says `invalid operator '$in' code: 15999`.

Comment: You will need 3.4 version. db.version() on shell to check your version. I can add the workaround if you need for lower versions.

Comment: You can use workaround mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444888/filter-array-using-the-in-operator-in-the-project-stage?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: It looks like both shell and DB are version 3.2.3.  But I just downloaded and installed it a few days ago.  Why should I have gotten an old version?

Comment: may be the installation didnt go through. use  `$setIsSubset: [["$$q.Label"],["fname","lname"]]`   inside cond.

Comment: I'm seeing an error that says `Unrecognized parameter to $filter: $setIsSubset`

Comment: Did you try `"cond":{$setIsSubset: [["$$q.Label"],["fname","lname"]]}` ?